# Using touch event + jquery-ui sortable on mobile not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

**Context:**

I'm making a web application for mobile devices. I'm using *jquery-ui sortable* for sort a items list where the first and last items are not sortable.

**The Goal:**

My goal is use the *jquery-mobile* tap-hold event to enable the *jquery-ui sortable* library so the user can sort the item that he tapped. When the user put the item in the right place, I want to disable the *jquery-ui sortable* again.

**The Problem:**

In terms of usability, what I want is that the user tap the screen, stay holding for x seconds and without stop holding , could start sort the item. This is not happening. What it is happening is you need to stop holding for the *jquery-ui sortable* catch the event and allow the user to sort the item that he wants.

**The Code:**

Follows the core of the code that I'm using. You don't need a mobile device to reproduce the error.

**EDIT**

I detect that I need the *touch-puch* javascript library to simulate touch events for *jquery-ui* work. Basically the library converts touch events to mouse events. But the original problem was not solved.

```js
function initializeSortablePages() {
 var sortableParentDiv = $(".sortable");
 var sortableDivs = $(".sortable .to-move");
 
 $(sortableParentDiv).sortable({
  items: sortableDivs,
  stop: function (event, ui) {
   disableSortablePages(sortableParentDiv);
  }
 });
  
 addTapHoldEventToSortablePages(sortableParentDiv, sortableDivs)
 disableSortablePages(sortableParentDiv);
 
}

function addTapHoldEventToSortablePages(sortableParentDiv, sortableDivs) {
 var thisLib = this;
 $(sortableDivs).bind('taphold', function (event, ui) {
  enableSortablePages(sortableParentDiv);  
 });
}

function enableSortablePages(sortableParentDiv) {
 $(sortableParentDiv).sortable("enable");
}

function disableSortablePages(sortableParentDiv) {
 $(sortableParentDiv).sortable("disable");
}

initializeSortablePages();
```

```css
.sortable div{
 width: 100px;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: white;
 margin-top: 20px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 background-color: #d4d4d4;
 padding-left:10px;
 cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>sortable demo</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
  <div class="sortable">
   <div>Item 1</div>
   <div class="to-move">Item 2</div>
   <div class="to-move">Item 3</div>
   <div class="to-move">Item 4</div>
   <div>Item 5</div>
 </div>
 <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are `thisLib.addTapHoldEventToSortablePages()` and `thisLib.disableSortablePages()` defined? I see functions created, yet I do not see them added as attributes of the object.

Comment: Hi @Twisty.
Because I adapted the code to show a simple version of him, i forgot to remove the "thisLib". Please, check the edit. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is a worthwhile example.

Working: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pzngpwvq/10/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var thisLib = {
    sortParentDiv: ".sortable",
    sortDivs: ".to-move",
    init: function() {
      console.log("Initialization Started.");
      var self = this;
      $(self.sortParentDiv).sortable({
        disabled: true,
        items: "> " + self.sortDivs,
        stop: function(e, ui) {
          self.disableSortPages(e);
        }
      });
      $(self.sortParentDiv + " div").disableSelection();
      self.addTapHoldEvent();
      //self.disableSortPages();
      console.log("Initialization completed.");
    },
    addTapHoldEvent: function() {
      var self = this;
      $(self.sortParentDiv).on("taphold", self.sortDivs, function(e) {
        self.enableSortPages.call(self, e)
      });
      console.log("TapHold bound to ", $(self.sortDivs));
    },
    removeTapHoldEvent: function() {
      var self = this;
      $(self.sortParentDiv).off("taphold", self.sortDivs);
      console.log("TapHold unbound to ", $(self.sortDivs));
    },
    enableSortPages: function(e) {
      console.log("Handler - Enable Sort |", e.type, e.target);
      var self = this;
      console.log(self);
      $(".ui-sortable-handle").addClass("active");
      self.removeTapHoldEvent.apply(self);
      $(self.sortParentDiv).sortable("enable");
    },
    disableSortPages: function() {
      console.log("Handler - Disable Sort");
      var self = this;
      $(self.sortDivs).removeClass("active");
      $(self.sortParentDiv).sortable("disable");
      self.addTapHoldEvent();
    }
  };

  thisLib.init();
});
```

When started, sortable is initialized with `disabled` true. We also bound `taphold` callback to enable the sorting. We remove the `taphold` binding to ensure there is no confusing as the user performs tap and hold actions while sorting.

now user can perform sort. When sort is complete, `taphold` is is bound again and sort is disabled.

So far only tested in desktop browser, but you can test on mobile at https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pzngpwvq/10/show/

Hope this helps make it more clear.

As you mentioned in your Edit, you will need to make use of Touch Punch library to translate `tap` to `click` etc so that jQuery UI can handle the activities.

**Update**

Added in Touch Punch and tested w/Chrome and FireFox on Android: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pzngpwvq/11/show/

Comment: Hi @Twisty. Thank you for your help. But the problem as not been solved. What you are doing is more or less what I'm doing. You need to tap and hold, then get out our finger from the screen and then you are able to start sorting the elements. What I want is, after the tap&hold and without get out the finger from the screen, the jquery-ui sortable starts the drag on target of the tap&hold.

Comment: @RicardoRocha not sure if you will be able to accomplish that. You may have to change the logic in a sense where sortable is always enabled yet tap&hold allows the sort to begin or triggers `start`.

Comment: I think I've found the solution. I will test it and if it works, I will put it as an answer